# The automated Stack Exchange / Feeds user is now participating in chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, feed, easter-eggs

Well, the robots are here.

User -2 that goes by "Stack Exchange" or "Feeds" has been posting conversational chat messages. See [recent Stack Overflow chat messages](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/-2/feeds?tab=recent) and [recent Stack Exchange chat messages](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-2/stack-exchange?tab=recent).

> To use this 'feature', type "translate: " before the message you want it to say.

Is this an easter egg, or has the bot truly [become sentient](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17289316#17289316)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you mean this one:

[image]

The important thing there is the deleted message immediately before it, which was:

```
translate: H4XX0RD!
```

So, try typing:

```
translate: チャットは今翻訳をサポートします。
```

The "post a translate message, then delete it" is arguably abuse of the system. If people don't get over that, I will make changes to prevent it.

Edit: this will be prevented in about 5 minutes; deleting the original message will also delete the subsequent message.

Comment: So I'm guessing chat wide translation is a feature now? I didn't think that was going public.

Comment: And if it turns out to be a bad idea, we'll revoke it

Comment: You may also want to make it a Reply to the message that triggered it to make it even more obvious.

Comment: @Powerlord I need to make some minor rendering tweaks to enable that - the arrow would be good, but I don't want the visible `@person`. In terms of storage, it *already is a reply* - we have a bit field that specifies whether the reply UI elements are visible, separate to whether it actually is a reply.

Comment: @MarcGravell is it intentional that the markdown is not copied correctly into the translated message, as I tried [here](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2338799#2338799)?

Comment: Ugh, you're no fun.

Comment: @rene GIGO, basically

Comment: Some people are toying with it by editing the message, perhaps that should also be prevented.

Comment: @Stijn sigh; this is why we can't have nice things

Comment: @Marc Feeds turned insane, replying "this is why we can't have nice things" on everything linking to this question.

Comment: I can confirm that 0_0

Comment: anything went wrong? or you guys are playing something?
we are getting "this is why we can't have nice things" for each message from feed.

Answer (score 36):

They're not only participating, but instead invading...

[image: ?]

Spamming with links to this thread... We're doomed!

---

Fixed, but `translate:` no longer works. RIP Feeds User, 26 Aug 2014 12:32 PM

Please all remember [his last words...](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2344706#2344706)

[image: "Feeds is a terrible person / bot!"]

Comment: test comment....

Comment: @Braiam Test failed, the world blew up.

Comment: you'll get it tomorrow, don't worry :) or you want to wait until bounty expires?

Comment: Now please reach the rep cap at 700 or more repz.

Answer (score 5):

Plonk to the rescue ...

[image: Plonk]

Comment: To late, it's "dead".

Comment: You were to slow. It seems that the Feeds got disabled for the time being.