# Full list of commands in chat

Tags: discussion, chat

In chat, there are some commands such as "translate" and "wiki". The "translate" command accepts any language and translates that text to English (the Stack Exchange/Feeds user replies with the English text), and "wiki: yourtexthere" transforms your message into a Wikipedia onebox to the article you referred (see [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17318012#17318012) and [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17317940#17317940) message).

Is there a full list of these commands available?

Comment: Might be experimental features so good chance some of them will not survive. But agree it would be nice to see a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "translate" command started as something nice to have, probably on a whim by [Marc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) (i.e. not an official feature), and was removed after being abused by many users.

Marc tried to fight it, e.g. in [The automated Stack Exchange / Feeds user is now participating in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238453/the-automated-stack-exchange-feeds-user-is-now-participating-in-chat) but eventually gave up four days later and nuked this featue with a blast of ["This is why we can't have nice things" all over chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238622/152859):

> Yes, yes; I was turning off the much-abused translate bot; I intended for subsequent use of translate: foo to result in that message, but... an if block got in the wrong place. Bad things. Very bad things. Fixed; data cleansed (but still tidying up a bit...)

I am pretty sure this abuse also prevented any further features, and we won't ever see anything like that again, as people will always abuse it.

Answer (score 3):

Neither of the commands you mention are still active.

The "translate: text to translate" was moderator only most recently but it stopped working in May of 2017.

They've also added automatic oneboxing for links from a few sites, so you don't need a command for them.

This includes:

- Stack Exchange (for posts that haven't been deleted)

  - post links
  - comment links
  - chat message links
- Wikipedia
- Amazon
- XKCD (includes hover text!)
- Twitter
- Image URLs convert to images in most cases

Comment: I don't think oneboxing is relevant, afaik it existed from the very beginning and not considered a "command" as OP here asks for. Better remove this part, or just mention onebox exists, but not elaborate about it. (Not on this question anyway, might be worth a separate one if doesn't exist yet.)

Comment: Both `define:` and `wiki:` seem to work (for non-mods too) at the moment.