# Feeds user has gone crazy

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

If we post any message (both in Tavern on the Meta and Shadow's Den, and also the chat.SE Sandbox, probably more rooms), the Feeds user replies "this is why we can't have nice things".

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: IT'S EVERYWHERE!

Comment: President should go down to the bunker, the world is at risk!!

Comment: PANIC!!! THE END IS NIGH!!!

Comment: Also affects [The Nineteenth Byte](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte).

Comment: @JanDvorak: I don't think so. The screenshot is not relevant, really.

Comment: Seems to have been fixed. Many thanks to the brave heroes.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238453/the-automated-stack-exchange-feeds-user-is-now-participating-in-chat/238617#comment781989_238617 :(

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, yes; I was turning off the [much-abused translate bot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238453/the-automated-stack-exchange-feeds-user-is-now-participating-in-chat); I *intended* for subsequent use of `translate: foo` to result in that message, but... an if block got in the wrong place. Bad things. Very bad things. Fixed; data cleansed (but still tidying up a bit...)

Comment: ETA when translate bot will be back?

Comment: @ShadowWizard when people can resist the urge to abuse it... so...

Comment: @ShadowWizard actually, for moderators it will be back in a few minutes, but note: translations now get posted in your own name, not a system user

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/APoAZ.png

Comment: So the feature is removed for non moderators?

Comment: @ShadowWizard for the moment, yes; it was being abused too much; I might re-enable it at a later date, with the "posts as you" tweak

Comment: Sorry to hear, though can't really say I'm surprised. Hope to see it back at some point.

Comment: This is why we can't have nice things.

Comment: @MarcGravell It's still very much borken. It's posting as the wrong user...

Comment: @fredley whimper; I should have stated in bed today. Will fix it later.

Comment: @fredley for info, it is almost certainly the different between chat user ids and q&a user ids. On some sites they are always the same. On others: not

Comment: Have a sympathy upvote from me ... I'm sure everybody here has great respect for you and the team ... even if you have an off-day ;)  take care!