# The Feeds bot’s translate command is no longer working for moderators

Tags: bug, chat, moderator-tools, feed, translations

Up till a few days ago, moderators in a chatroom were able to get the Feeds chatbot to translate things for us using the `translate: blah` or `translate xx: unblah` commands. This was disabled for regular users [quite some time ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238453/153355) but it’s always still worked for moderators.

Sometimes we can still get it do something or other, but not often, not consistently, and not well: for the most part it just sits there like a dead parrot.

This is a useful and convenient tool. Could we please get it fixed?

Comment: Aghh, one minute! And I provided screenshots!

Comment: @Mithrandir “Time is the crucible in which we burn.” :)

Comment: One minor thing: the Feeds doesn't post it. It shows up as a message from you.

Comment: I guess moderators also started to abuse it. Be thankful Marc wasn't upset enough to have it write "this is why we can't have nice things" as reply to every chat message, anywhere, like he did last time. (which. I must admit, was **brilliant** revenge.) :)